# how to migrate msAccess Database to MySQL with relationship?

Tags: mysql, ms-access

Is anybody know how to migrate MsAccess DB to MySQL with all relationship ?

I tired to find it on internet but i can just import DB without relationship.

if anybody knows this please tell me the steps of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To export MsAccess 2007( and above) database to Mysql follow this steps.

Step 1: you need download tool from below link: 
http://www.bullzip.com/products/a2m/info.php
Then follow step given on that link.

**Note: It require a 32-bit MySql OBCD Driver. If you have 64-bit OS still we need 32-bit MySql ODBC Driver.**

***If this driver not installed on your computer, it also allow to create Mysql Dump file directly. To do this follow this steps.***

Step 1: click Yes

[image]

Step 2: click next

[image]

Step 3: Select MsAcess database and click next.

[image]

Step 4: Select location where you want to create dump file and select empty schema name where you want to dump the data and click next.

[image]

Step 5: It will ask to select table you want to export so in my case i want to export all tables of MsAcess database to MySql. After selecting tables click next.

[image]

Step 6: Select transfer option if you need. In my case i do not need to modify any settings. It automatically select some necessary option when it appear on screen. And click on "Run Now" button.

[image]

After click on "Run Now" button it will show progress and after completion "Exit" will appear, Click on Exit button and that's it.

**Now you have .sql file and execute it in mysql.**

Answer (score 0):

You might find tools to import MS Access tables to MySQL but relationships, you have to redefine them!(best practice) Use workbench to generate db diagram from your imported tables and then you can visually recreate the relationships like in ms Access.

i've used: http://www.bullzip.com/products/a2m/info.php